# What would be the resultant of two vectors at 180°?

Tags: vectors

If two vectors are at 180° to each other, would the resultant be 0 (as per the head-to-tail method), or the difference of the magnitudes of the two vectors? If the former is true, then why isn't it the difference of the magnitudes? Technically, if one force is 4N forward and the other force is 11n backwards, then shouldn't the resultant be 11-4 = 7N backwards? Yet that would mean an exception to the head-to-tail method... So thanks in advance.

Also, I have another small question... What's the use of a Cross Product, are there any examples where a vector is calculated by cross-multiplying two vectors? thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes sometimes most trivial tings have puzzled me too, Think hard and you will get the answer, if not use paper, pencil and compass to understand vector addition. take two vectors and try to add them at different angle. My good wishes are with you.

Comment: You must have done head-to-tail twice. Yet you're only adding another vector once. No! You'll break the arrow!

Comment: the resultant is not 0 in head-to-tail. The one with greater force will have longer arrow backwards.

Comment: Thanks to all three comments :) I realised my stupid assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The head to tail does work here and the answer is the difference in magnitude.

Try imagining a triangle and then collapsing it so that the vertex lies on the opposite side. You'll understand why it is difference in magnitude of the vectors.

Comment: @user3724492 you're welcome.